# Gtk image doesn't show up in C

Tags: c, gtk

Hello I have some trouble about GTK, I use the file_chooser_dialog to select an image and opened it just after I clicked on "OK" but that doesn't work and that show nothing at all. Can someone explain this to me please ?
Here the code and thanks for answering.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>



static void open_file(GtkWidget* pOpen, gpointer pWindow, GtkWidget* pTable,)
{        
GtkWidget *image = NULL;
GtkWidget *open;
open = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new("Select a file", GTK_WINDOW(pWindow),
GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN, GTK_STOCK_OK, GTK_RESPONSE_OK, 
    GTK_STOCK_CANCEL, GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL, NULL);
    gtk_widget_show_all(open);
    gtk_file_chooser_set_current_folder(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(open),
    g_get_home_dir());
gint resp = gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(open));
if(resp == GTK_RESPONSE_OK)
    {
            GtkFileChooser *chooser = GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(open);
            image = gtk_image_new_from_file(gtk_file_chooser_get_filename(chooser));
            gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(pTable),image,
            8,12,10,20);
    }
else
    g_print("You pressed Cancel\n");
gtk_widget_destroy(open);
} 

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
//Variable
GtkWidget *pWindow = NULL;
GtkWidget *pLabel = NULL;
GtkWidget *pTable = NULL;
GtkWidget *pButton = NULL;
GtkWidget *pOpen = NULL;  



//Iniatialisation && attributs
gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
pWindow = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(pWindow), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(pWindow), 720, 480);
pTable = gtk_table_new(40,20, TRUE);
pButton = gtk_button_new_with_label("Open Image");




//Position of the box
gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(pTable), pButton,
3,7,5,7);
gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(pTable), pLabel,
3,7,8,9);
gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(pTable), image,
3,7,1,3);

//add the table to the main window
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(pWindow), GTK_WIDGET(pTable));

//Signal
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(pWindow), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(pButton), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(open_file), NULL);
gtk_widget_show_all(pWindow);
gtk_main();
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You read the global (uninitialized!) variable `path` before starting the mainloop and then never do it again. The `path` variable gets first populated as a callback within the `gtk_main()` line, which handles UI, signals and a bunch of other things.

Comment: mainloop ? you mean the main function ? I'm pretty new at using GTK  and I might not understand what you mean

Comment: `gtk_main` is The mainloop which processes all gsignals and callbacks from within there. ASK yourself Ehen the `pButton` clicked callback gets executed.

Comment: SO I have to put a gsignal when the user clicked on "ok" and use a callback from the main function ?

Comment: You are already doing that (well you hook a callback to the `clicked` signal provided by button, which is totally fine). The point is that you never load anything from disk. You either need to destroy and recreate the image or read image data from file. Just updating path is not enough, GtImage does not watch the change of a variable. Read the API docs. They are helpful in fact.

Comment: I change the callback function and load an image with the path (I modified the code in my original post) but I don't know why this still doesn't work

Comment: you never attach the image to the table

Comment: I change my original post, I'm sorry to bother you again but I have a new error  "Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_table_attach: assertion 'GTK_IS_TABLE (table)' failed" I don't know why attachement failed

Comment: The callback function of "clicked" should take exactly 2 arguments. The third one you use is just random bogus memory, and thus most likely a pointer to invalid unallocated memory. Please make sure you understand the namespace of variables. Just because you name 2 variables the same does not mean they are one and very same object/pointer.